# Python : Logging : Removing StreamHandler

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to remove StreamHandler during runtime of my python code execution.

```
if (False == consoleOutput):                                                                                                                                                                
    lhStdout = log.handlers[0]  # stdout is the only handler initially                                                                                                                      
    log.removeHandler(lhStdout)
```

This is working fine. But I don't like that we assume that stdout is the first handler in handler array. Is there a way to query handlers class to find which type it is? Something like this

```
 for handler in log.handlers
    if (handler.type == StreamHandler())
        <...>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is spelled: `if isinstance(handler, StreamHandler):` - but I'd really like to know **why** you want to do such a thing instead of using the sensible solution (ie not configuring a StreamHandler for your logger at all...).

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
On your question, why not use StreamHandler? IO reasons? Or cheaper alternatives available (use Filehandler, and do tail?)

Comment: My question was not "why not use StreamHandler" but why would you have your code remove something from the logger's configuration at all. If it's application code, then _your_ code is responsible for configuring the loggers and you just have to NOT use StreamHandlers in your configuration. And if it's library code, then BY ALL MEAN *DO NOT* mess with the logger's configuration, it's the application's code duty, not yours. TL;DR : if you want to remove a handler from a logger, then you are not using logging the right way, period.

Comment: *"if you want to remove a handler from a logger, then you are not using logging the right way"* Not true, sadly. Some libraries add a streamhandler to their logger, and the calling application may want to remove it.

Comment: @Kylotan I've not seen such a case so far but you indeed have a point here. Now it means it's the library not using logging the right way, so the proper solution here would be to patch the library and contribute the patch - assuming it's OSS of course.

Comment: Sanic is one that does - https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/master/sanic/log.py; the formatters are more or less necessary in order to make the logging useful, so I'm not sure how they could go about providing that in a useful way without specifying the handlers (it seems like handlers and formatters are coupled incorrectly in python's core logging...)

Comment: @ElYobo "I'm not sure how they could go about providing (the formatters) in a useful way without specifying the handlers" => quite simply by defining them and providing them so you can use them in your configuration - which actually seems to be the case here,  the module you linked to defines a logging configuration and a couple loggers that you can use (or not) but does NOT configure the logging by itself (no call to `logging.config`).

Comment: They do make use of it as well[1], but they do also allow you to override that configuration.

[1] https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/master/sanic/app.py#L53

Comment: @ElYobo this is actually in the applicative part, not the library one, so it's at the right place -  and as you mention you have the option to either pass your own config or just plain bypass the logging config. What I was talking about was _library_ code, which should _use_ logging but never _configure_ it since the library author cannot know the logging needs of apps using the library. Decoupling logging usage from logging config is one of the main point of the stdlib's logging package actually.